# All I got was/were macarons. All I had was a bruise and a cut

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, expressions, subject-verb-agreement

I need to ask what does "got" in this sentence mean?

> All I got was/were macarons

Does it mean I "received" macarons or I have got (as in possession) macarons? And why did we used "was/were", why not "is/are?"

Secondly likewise sentence is "All I got was this lousy t-shirt" why we used "was" why not "All I got is this lousy t-shirt"?

Thirdly, do you not think "All I had were bruise and cut" would be correct instead of "All I had was a bruise and a cut" because "a bruise and a cut" are collectively plural since we used "and" not "or" as in "a bruise and a cut"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard English, *got* means *possessing* only with *have*:

*All I've got is the clothes I stand up in*.

In colloquial speech, the /v/ sometimes gets elided, and you hear *I got a car outside*, with that meaning.

But that sense is inconsistent with the past tense *was*. In *All I got was X*, the *got* has to be the simple past of *get*, meaning *received*.

(I don't know what *macarons* means: a *macaroon* is a kind of cake or biscuit)

With a present *is*, it is more likely to have the *possessing* sense, because that is inconsistent with a past reading of *got*.

So, in summary:

> All I got was X: almost certainly, "all I received"

> All I got is X: probably "all I have", but this is not standard English, which would require *All I've got.*

Similarly, *All I got was **a** lousy t-shirt* means *received*. (You understand the joke? Somebody went somewhere, and all they brought back for me was this t-shirt). *All I got is a lousy t-shirt* is non-standard for "all I've got" or "all I have".

As for *was* vs *were*: both are possible in your first and last examples, depending on whether you are thinking of it as one thing or several.

Comment: Colin - see [this](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/whats-the-difference-between-macarons-and-macaroons#macaron-vs-macaroons-whats-the-difference) I'd never heard of macarons either until recently.

Comment: @KateBunting Same, I've seen the word but assumed it was a typo/misspelling.  Now I know better! ...It's a weird feeling being humbled by a small dessert cookie.

Comment: @BruceWayne To make it even more confusing, in English the French pastries are often called macaroons as well -- Google image search "macaroon," and you'll see a pretty even split between French things and coconut things. In some contexts calling the French pastry a "macaron" in English can give a snobby vibe